# Symfony : sonata admin bundle install error

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, sonata-admin, sonata

I'm trying to install sonata on a new Symfony 3 project.

I follow this installation guide : https://tech.acseo.co/symfony-sonata-admin-tutoriel/ ( dev-master )

I run these commands :

```
composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle "dev-master"
composer require sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle "dev-master"
```

But I have these errors in my console :

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle[dev-master].
    - sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle dev-master requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requir
ement.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

It's the first time I use sonata, can you help me ? 
Thanks you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your composer.json you have this.

```
"config": {
"platform": {
    "php": "5.5.9"
   }
 },
```

This overrides your PHP version and you see this error`your PHP version (5.6.25) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5.9)`. Remove it
since Sonata needs PHP > 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases another trick can help. While you are installing any package by compose you can use `--ignore-platform-reqs`.

Therefor, you could try

```
composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle "dev-master" --ignore-platform-reqs
```

The only problem, that this cheat can break down your dependencies in future, or the bundle you installed use language features of new version, that are incompatible with your minor version.

Using of "`--ignore-platform-reqs`" - is your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, I've installed this https://github.com/pierre-vassoilles/symfony2-sonata-base-project

and it works :D

Thank you for your answer :)